# Understanding the OpenCV fitEllipse approach

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to figure out the documented approach to the OpenCV fitEllipse usage.

It can be found here: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/de/dc7/fitellipse_8cpp-example.html

The problem is that it applies a threshold onto the image, based on the slider position, but the only line relating the slider value, to the original image is:

> Mat bimage = image >= sliderPos;

Yet that >= there makes no sense to me, and using imshow on bimage/image shows them as equal.

Can someone please explain what is happening there?
I'm sorry If it is obvious. I'm not a great C++ programmer (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details) it is a binarization (0 or 255):

> Comparison: A cmpop B, A cmpop alpha, alpha cmpop A, where cmpop is
>   one of >, >=, ==, !=, <=, <. The result of comparison is an 8-bit
>   single channel mask whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular
>   element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

Now I try to explain the more technical part of which functions are called.
Following the [example you gave](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/de/dc7/fitellipse_8cpp-example.html#gsc.tab=0) first we should know the types of the variables:

- `image` and `bimage` are [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#gsc.tab=0)
- `sliderPos` is of type `int`.

The function for the operator `>=` can be found in [`mat.hpp`](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/2.4/dc/dc2/mat_8hpp.html) which is indirectly included by the other includes. The function we were looking for is:

```
MatExpr cv::operator>= (const Mat &a, double s)
```

In [`matop.cpp`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matop.cpp) it calls:

```
MatOp_Cmp::makeExpr(e, CV_CMP_GE, a, b);
```

which then calls (line 1408):

```
res = MatExpr(&g_MatOp_Cmp, cmpop, a, b, Mat(), 1, 1);
```

This internally applies a generic operator on the given parameters (matrices a and b here). The result (thus of the part `image >= sliderPos`) is of type [`MatExpr`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html). 
Finally the following [function](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2a0798475170fb3a23b5bc63686de334) of `Mat bimage` is called:

```
Mat& cv::Mat::operator= (const MatExpr & expr)
```

which sets the `Mat bimage` to the resulting `MatExpr` object's value.

Comment: That seems to answer. I've got to test it though, since I'm almost sure that having both 'bimage' and 'image' both appeared the same using imshow.

I've made binary images using threshold or inRange (i think), but never saw that >= trick.

I'll mark it an answer after testing.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
createTrackbar("threshold", "result", &sliderPos, 255, processImage);
```

the fourth parameter (`255`) is the maximum slider value. The minimum is always `0`. `sliderPos` will thus assume a value in the range `[0,255]`.

This line:

```
Mat bimage = image >= sliderPos;
```

is a simple binarization: `bimage` is a binary image where each pixel has value 255 if corresponding value in `image` is `>=` than `sliderPos`, or 0 otherwise.
It's the same as:

```
Mat bimage;
threshold(image, bimage, sliderPos-1, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

`bimage` and `image` are different. `bimage` has only `0` or `255` values, while `image` can have any value in the range `[0,255]`.